# IE 6 OR IE Tester -

Tags: internet-explorer-6

took me a long time to figure this out and was wondering if it is IE 6, IE TESTER or something i have done.

im creating a session to store quotes, which i am using `md5($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])`

The problem being when i tested in IE 6 in the IE tester application, results are being inserted but the quotes are not being retrieved.

After some digging and looking i found that the token being used to retrieve the quotes and the token being used to insert the quotes where different.

On the main page, i added this;

```
<p><input type="hidden" id="quoteID2" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; ?>" /></p>
<p><input type="hidden" id="quoteID3" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; ?>" /></p>
```

which returned;

```
<p><input type="hidden" id="quoteID2" value="Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.2)" /></p>
<p><input type="hidden" id="quoteID3" value="127.0.0.1" /></p>
```

which i was expecting.

yet when i applied the same test to the php script that was inserting the data it returned this;

> Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.2)
>   127.0.0.1

can anyone tell me why it is saying that the second script is being ran through IE 8 ?!?!

regards,

Phil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted by the IE team many times, tools like IETester are inherently less reliable than testing with the real browsers, because the approach they use is an unsupported hack, and leads to crashes and cases where the "real" IE binaries get munged with the older ones you're trying to test. You should test IE6 using the free VPC that Microsoft provides.

http://www.enhanceie.com/ie/webdev.asp#vpc

Comment: ... or just drop support for IE6 altogether.

Comment: I would love to, I really would but the folk who ring me up saying they have got some work for me all use IE6, and when they show potential clients my work, it wont look good will it. Stupid IE 6